# How to use a spring bean within SOAPHandler

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jax-ws, autowired

I just want to use a spring bean within `handleMessage()` method which is called in handler-chain.xml.

This is my handler-chain.xml:

```
<jaxws:bindings>
    <handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
        <!-- ====================== -->
        <!-- service based handlers -->
        <!-- ====================== -->
        <handler-chain>
            <handler>
                <handler-name>CustomerHandler</handler-name>
                <handler-class>com.test.ws.handler.CustomerHandler</handler-class>
            </handler>
        </handler-chain>
    </handler-chains>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

And also this is my CustomerHandler.java class:

```
public class CustomerHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

@Autowired
public ServiceInvokeUtil serviceInvokeUtil;

public Set<QName> getHeaders() {

    return null;
}

public void close(MessageContext context) {

}

public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    logSoapMessage(context);
    return false;
}

public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {


    Boolean isRequest = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();
    // if this is a request, true for outbound messages, false for inbound
    if (isRequest) {

        try {
            SOAPEnvelope soapEnv = soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
            SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnv.getHeader();

            // if no header, add one
            if (soapHeader == null) {
                soapHeader = soapEnv.addHeader();
            }
            Boolean oa = serviceInvokeUtil.createRecord(SoapUtil.getRecordEntity());

            SOAPElement userContextHeader = ConsumerHeaderHelper.createUserContextHeader(context);
            soapHeader.addChildElement(userContextHeader);
            }
            soapMsg.saveChanges();




        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    } else {

        try {
            SoapUtil.setSoapResponseHeader(soapMsg.getSOAPHeader());
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    logSoapMessage(context);
    return true;
}
```

This is my spring configuration xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring
http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder />

<bean id="serviceInvokeUtil" class="com.test.ws.util.ServiceInvokeUtil">
</bean>
```

When I am calling a web service, the spring bean `serviceInvokeUtil` is null.
How to use `serviceInvokeUtil` class as a spring bean within `handleMessage` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extended SpringBeanAutowiringSupport to CustomerHandler class than it was solved. Like this:                                                            public class CustomerHandler extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements SOAPHandler {.....

Answer (score 0):

Spring will processes @Autowired annotation only if it will control creation of instance. In other words, your CustomerHandler have to be bean as well as ServiceInvokeUtil to force spring autowire it.

Comment: Firstly, thank yo for relpy. I've already tried it. I put customerHandler class in spring configuration xml as a spring bean. Like this:                            <bean id="customerHandler" class="com.test.ws.handler.CustomerHandler"</bean> But result is same. Do you have any diffrent ideas?